# Will executing system "ping" command in my android application cause questions from Google on publishing?

Tags: android, permissions, ping

I am implementing an app which can ping remote hosts, get ping measurements and use them further for different purposes.
My question is, is it okay to use android system ping command? Does it need any special permissions except android.permission.INTERNET?

Is there any chance Google will ask any questions about system command execution or even refuse to publish it?

My code:

```
private static String ping(String url, int testAmount) {
    String str = null;
    try {
        Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(
                "/system/bin/ping -W 1 -c " + testAmount + " " + url);
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                process.getInputStream()));
        int i;
        char[] buffer = new char[4096];
        StringBuffer output = new StringBuffer();
        while ((i = reader.read(buffer)) > 0)
            output.append(buffer, 0, i);
        reader.close();

        str = output.toString();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Ping Exception: ", e);
    }
    return str;
}
```

It returns a string containing ping command output